# Would and would have

Tags: would

What's the difference between would and would have in the past?

He thought he would win

He thought he would have won

I know that "would" is for regular actions in the past and "would have" about some possibility or probability for instance sentence like that I would win it means that is happened many times in the past right? And I would have won it means that I didn't win or I'm not sure if I won, yes? Do these sentences have any more meaning except for which I mentioned here?

Comment: Please edit to show what you've already found in your research and explain more about how you're confused. These are two different tenses, and they behave as expected.

Comment: I know that would is for regular actions in the past and would have about some possibility or probability for instance  sentnece like that I would win it means that is happened many times in the past right? And I would have won it means that I didn't win or I'm not sure if I won, yes? Do these sentences have any more meaning except for which I mentioned here?

Comment: Thanks; if you don't mind, I added that explanation to the question

Comment: And could answer my questions now, please?

Comment: He thought he would win:  before the game ended, he expected to win or after the game ended, be was confirmed in his belief that victory was soon his.  Without context, it's not always possible to identify the time-reference of modals.

Answer (score 1):

We have a lot of "time travel" tenses here. Let's make a timeline and travel along it:

- October 1, contest day, 8:00 am: He says "I think I'll win." He's in the present, making a statement about the future (let's say the race is in two hours).
- Oct 1, 10 am: He runs in the race and doesn't win.
- October 2, the next day: He says "I thought I would win." He's in the present, talking about a moment in the past (8 am yesterday), *and how in that moment* he was thinking about *what was* the future (10 am yesterday).

Whew! Now let's add "would *have*." It could mean several different things, and we would need context to help know which.

- It could be adding even more "time traveling": "I thought I *would have* won by 10:30... but in fact I won at 10:45." Here he's talking about a moment in the past (10:30 yesterday) at which he expected something to *have already happened*.
- It could be a "conditional." "Would" often goes along with "if" to describe something that isn't true or didn't happen, but could have. "I *would* offer you a drink... *if* I had anything." The "if" can even be implied but unsaid: "You went to the movies? I *would* have gone too!" (... *if* you had asked me.) So he could be saying "I thought I *would have* won..." ("*if* I'd run faster").
- Finally, it could be actually doing nothing to change the meaning of "I thought I would win." Just like "I won!" and "I have won!" have pretty much the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much.